# function not called in promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I've been looking all over for an answer for this, as I am sure it must have been asked before, but I can't seem to find one that makes sense to me.

In node I'm creating a couple of Firebase 'watchers' that handles some sanitization of my data in my Firebase and to send an SMS when the status of a parameter changes. In the below code I've got a `startChildChangedWatcher` and a `sendSMS` function. My problem occurs when I try to call `sendSMS` from within the promise in `bitly.shorten()`. It never gets executed, although it works fine when called outside of the promise. I've tried defining `var self = this;` because I thought it had to do with scope, and then calling `self.sendSMS("")`, but no luck. Also, only one of the two log statements inside the promise gets called. I'm sure this is pretty simple, but sometimes it's difficult to know what exactly to search for when looking for similar answers.

```
ref.authWithCustomToken(token, function(error, authData){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login successful");
    startChildChangedWatcher();
    ...
  }
});

var startChildChangedWatcher = function() {

  deliveriesRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());

    if (snapshot.val().completed === true) {
      if (snapshot.val().urlToShorten !== undefined) {
        console.log("Image url found, proceeding to shorten url");
        bitly.shorten(snapshot.val().urlToShorten)
        .then(function(response) {
          var shortUrl = response.data.url;

          //This prints fine
          console.log('URL Received, sending SMS');
          sendSMS("Your url is: " + shortUrl);

          //This never prints
          console.log("Url shortened, proceeding to send sms");
        }, function(err){
          console.log(err)
        });
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }
  });
};

var sendSMS = function(message) {
  console.log(message);
  twilio.sendMessage({
    to: +447564908855,
    from: +441241797052,
    body: message
  }, function(err, responseData) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error sending message: " + err);
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent. Response: " + responseData);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Does the sendSMS function get executed??

Comment: @himangshuj No, sorry forgot to put that in there. It doesn't.

Comment: You're mixing promises and callbacks. You're not going to have a good time. Can you try promisifying `authWithCustomToken`?

Comment: you might want to use shortUrl instead of url when calling sendSMS =)

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 sorry, SO 'edition' error ;) Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: @Droogans yes, I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: can you check if the sendSMS function is defined inside the callback. Do cosole.log(sendSMS) before calling sendSMS

Comment: @Droogans Promisifying it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have defined url in the code.

`sendSMS("Your url is: " + url);`
to 
`sendSMS("Your url is: " + shortUrl);`

```
ref.authWithCustomToken(token, function(error, authData){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login successful");
    startChildChangedWatcher();
    ...
  }
});

var startChildChangedWatcher = function() {

  deliveriesRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());

    if (snapshot.val().completed === true) {
      if (snapshot.val().urlToShorten !== undefined) {
        console.log("Image url found, proceeding to shorten url");
        bitly.shorten(snapshot.val().urlToShorten)
        .then(function(response) {
          var shortUrl = response.data.url;

          //This prints fine
          console.log('URL Received, sending SMS');
          sendSMS("Your url is: " + url);

          //This never prints
          console.log("Url shortened, proceeding to send sms");
        }, function(err){
          console.log(err)
        });
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }
  });
};

var sendSMS = function(message) {
  console.log(message);
  twilio.sendMessage({
    to: +447564908855,
    from: +441241797052,
    body: message
  }, function(err, responseData) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error sending message: " + err);
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent. Response: " + responseData);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Sorry, this was not the problem but a 'copy paste' error into SO